# Computing the total different between a pixel and its neighborhood

Tags: c++, performance, array, image, matlab

I have C++ code which written for mex in MATLAB. It used to compute the total different between a pixel and its neighborhood (8 neighborhood in my code). The code ran and gave me an expected result. However, I think that we can make my code more faster (because of a lot of `if` statement). I am very happy if someone can help me to speed up it.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#define img(i,j) img[(i) + (j)*M]
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    double  *img, *G; 
    int    N, M, class_count;
    int ndim=3;    
    double beta, energy;
    N           = (int) mxGetN(prhs[0]); //cols
    M           = (int) mxGetM(prhs[0]); //rows
    img         = (double *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    beta        = (double )*mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    class_count = (int )*mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    /* Initial zeros matrix*/
    int dims[3] = {M-2, N-2, class_count};
    plhs[0]     = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    G           = (double *) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    /////////////Main///////////////
    for (int label=2; label <= class_count+1; label++) {
       for (int i=1; i < M-1; i++) {        
         for (int j=1; j < N-1; j++) {                          
                energy = 0;
                 // North, south, east and west
                if (label == img(i-1,j)) energy = energy-beta;
                else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
                else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i+1,j)) energy = energy-beta;
                else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
                else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i-1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
                    else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i-1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
                    else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i+1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
                    else energy = energy+beta;
                if (label == img(i+1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
                    else energy = energy+beta;
                G[(i-1) + (j-1)* (M-2) + (label-2) * (N-2) * (M-2)]=energy;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if-else` statements are a problem, but not your main problem. Are you sure you need 3 `for` loops within each other?

Comment: Yes. my output is 3D matrix. Thus, it need 3 loop. For example, I have a matrix 100x100 and it has 4 labels. Then the output is 100x100x4. (Assume that I ignored the padding at corner)

Comment: Is C++14 supported?

Comment: How to know it? I am using Matlab 2015b. It used 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012' for  building c++

Comment: In that case C++11 is supported, but 14 probably not. Good to know, since I smell a lambda solution incoming.

Comment: i believe for if-else statements can be simplified by using`if (label == img(i,j)) energy += beta;else energy -= beta;` or i could be wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think it still does not improve computational time, becase of a lot of if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Measure your code

Since we don't have your data or your computer or your compiler, we're a little bit hampered in trying to identify things that will speed up your code.  However, **you** have access to all of those things, so rather than guess that it's the cause of the `if-then` constructs or anything else, the prudent thing to do would be to measure the code and find out (e.g. with a profiler) where your code is spending most of its time.  Armed with that data, you can begin to effectively target the real bottlenecks.

### Think about "locality of reference"

With modern computers, cacheing is often a factor in determining performance.  Generally, data items that are "close together" (that is, items that all fit in the cache at once) will be quicker to access than those that are "far apart" (that is, items that do not all fit in the cache at once).  For this reason, we can think about restructuring the algorithm to try to work on as small a memory footprint as possible.  In this case it's possible you can gain performance by simply rearranging the nested loops.  Right now, it looks like this:

```
for (int label=2; label <= class_count+1; label++) {
   for (int i=1; i < M-1; i++) {        
      for (int j=1; j < N-1; j++) {
```

But I think I'd try arranging things like this instead:

```
for (int j=1; j < N-1; j++) {                          
   for (int i=1; i < M-1; i++) {        
      for (int label=2; label <= class_count+1; label++) {
```

This way, the input data is accessed in a somewhat more sequential manner.  The output data is not, but because it's only accessed once per loop, I'm guessing that it makes less difference.

### Simplify your code

One of the things your code does is to either add or subtract an energy value if a particular value is matched.  Because integer math is often faster than floating point, you might benefit from restructuring your code.  Here's one way to do that.  Change the interior of the loop to look like this instead:

```
int energycount = 8;
if (label == img(i-1,j-1)) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i  ,j-1)) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i+1,j-1)) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i-1,j  )) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i+1,j  )) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i-1,j+1)) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i  ,j+1)) energycount -= 2;
if (label == img(i+1,j+1)) energycount -= 2;
G[(i-1) + (j-1)* (M-2) + (label-2) * (N-2) * (M-2)]=beta*energycount;
```

### Use `const` where practical

Many of these values are set once and then not changed.  The compiler may be able to find better optimizations if you explicitly tell it which values are `const`:

```
const int ndim = 3;    
const int N = (int) mxGetN(prhs[0]); //cols
const int M = (int) mxGetM(prhs[0]); //rows
const double *img = (double *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
const double beta = (double )*mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
const int class_count = (int )*mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
/* Initial zeros matrix*/
const int dims[3] = {M-2, N-2, class_count};
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
double *G = (double *) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
```

### Don't initialize large data items pointlessly

It appears that every member of `G` is initialized by the loop, so there's no real need to initialize it before that.  For that reason, I'd recommend using `mxCreateUninitNumericArray` to create an unitialized array rather than `mxCreateNumericArray` which initializes all values to 0.

Comment: Do you have MATLAB? I will give you the measurement script to test. I am using Matlab 2015a anhd your code give me an good solution, expect the changing (int label=2; label <= class_count+1; label++) { in in below loop. The link to download full code is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j74vl55glhq1z5t/AABtyujsOwPXre2x-Zdve7pYa?dl=0

Comment: No, I longer use Matlab, but I once did.  I'd be interested in learning your results when you time the before/after code.  You can post it here as a comment.

Comment: Yes. based on your comment. I changed it and it is really useful. your optimization code speeds up 1.38 times than my code without changing three loop order. If I changed if statement order, I only get 0.8479 times (means slower than my code)

Comment: Is this line right? `int energycount == 8;` Shouldn't that be a single `=`? If not can you explain what it does?

Comment: I think he typo it. It must be `int energycount =8;`

Comment: @user8430: You're right -- it's a typo, but fixed now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Edward: How about the first point "locality of reference". If I used it, the code becomes slower than without changing

Comment: @user8430: actually that's the second point.  The first point is "measure your code" -- and you are seeing now why that's important. I had a guess that rearranging the `for` loop nesting would improve things, but your measurements showed that theory was incorrect or that some other rearrangement would be better.  I'd try experimenting a bit with that to see which works best.